# PHP Only allow specific words in a string

Tags: php

I'm trying to check if the given string contains words that are not listen in my $allowed array. If it does I want them replaced with "".

So let's say my string contains "Hello World" and "World" is not in my allowed words it should replace "World" with "".

Another issue I have is that my current implementation is case sensitive.

```php
$string = "Test new world";
$allowed = array('hello', 'test');
if(in_array($string, $allowed)) {
     
}
else {
    // Return false or Replace with ""
}
```

Comment: show you code..

Comment: When to replace?on typing or on submitting?

Comment: What do you want to replace? By what? When? How? Need more details please

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PHP Filter text for banned words](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13987590/php-filter-text-for-banned-words)

Comment: @Sanguinary I want to only allow my words and remove everything else from the string.

Comment: @MickaelLeger I want to replace everything that is not in my allowed list with nothing.

Comment: @EyesReye : ok, but can you add some example? We have no idea how your `$data` looks like, what is your allowed words, etc..but try you can 1/ Create an array with all your allowed words / char, 2/ Check is the word is in this array, 3/ Is YES : do nothing, ELSE use str_replace

Comment: @MickaelLeger Thanks for the help i managed to fix it but is there a way that it checks for both case sensitive and case insensitive?, i've updated my question it now contains my current code.

Comment: Do **not** edit your question to another one if your original question was solved. Post a new question instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can answer partially by showing you how to keep word boundaried words, removing everything else from the string:

```
<?php

$input  = 'hotdogs are food, not actual HOT dogs.  The latter being dog animals that are hot.';

$words = 
[
    'hot',
    'dog'
];
$regex  = '@\b(' . implode($words, '|') . ')\b@i';
$output = '';
if(preg_match_all($regex, $input, $matches))
    $output = implode($matches[0]);

print $output;
```

Output:

```
HOTdoghot
```

Comment: (Can this be done with a preg_replace invert of some kind?)

Comment: This is what happens when OP changes his original question. We got several answers answering two different questions. Now this answers the original question and as it is what OP wanted to begin with, this should get accepted as the answer.

Comment: @Sanguinary, oh I see, all change, well perhaps it might help the OP refine their question.

Comment: @Sanguinary Sorry my bad, The code works exactly how i wanted it to work!

Answer (score 0):

To check for both cases made it upper or lower case both before comparison

```
$allowed = array('hello', 'test');

// Map every array element to be lowercase string
$lowercaseAllowed = array_map('strtolower', $allowed);

// Check if lower case version of data is in accepted lowercase array
if(in_array( strtolower($data), $lowercaseAllowed ) ) {
     //Do something
} else {
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work when string contains multiple words.

Comment: It should work. Show me your data to check.

Comment: If my string contains "HELLO test" it returns false.

Comment: So I checked it again and it's working http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/df2fdc5b2c70c111241499f338d741f6da41903b

Comment: That is because you have "hello test" in your allowed words, if possible i want to be able to put in multiple single words that it checks on.

Comment: Sorry, didn't get right what you wont from the start. For this task you can Implode your string as an array with space as a delimiter $stringAsArray = implode(' ', $string); and then do a foreach on each word in this array through this code. However if it will be something big you should defiantly use something else.

Answer (score 0):

With the example in your question and assuming that $data is a string containing just one word, you would just strtolower($data)

As in

```
if(in_array(strtolower($data), $allowed)) {
```

Comment: In this case you are also assuming that $allowed contains lowercase strings

Comment: well they did in his question, which is all we have to go on.